# how get thumbnail size in PHP WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

this is my php code and i want to add the size thumbnail max 300x420

```
<a class="blog-views" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php
the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a>
```

i have get from wordpress this code, but this do not help me, thumbnail, medium, mdeium large, large and full.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

Comment: why not just use `the_post_thumbnail('medium')` ? Or do you need exactly 300x420 px?

Comment: i want exactly 300x420, i dot know what i need to put or maybe i can change it with css, i have try but is not working, so i want to make this with 300x420 so in my home page the latest post is coming same thumbnails size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(300,420) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 420, true );

For more information follow this link [set_post_thumbnail_size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)

Answer (score 1):

You can change thumbnail size from admin side, wp-admin/options-media.php